# How to free draw and erase on a MATLAB GUI?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, draw, erase

I wanted to create a gui that worked as a canvas for free drawing lines with the mouse and with option of erasing...

anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to look at how other people have implemented this. For example, searching for [freehand on the File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/?search_submit=fileexchange&query=freehand&term=freehand) brings up [this freehand drawing function](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7347-freehanddraw).

As a basic idea, you'll want to either regularly capture the mouse position, or to evaluate a callback on mouse movement.